# Shift operator on the set of function $X = \{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let the linear space be $X = \{f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$, and define the shift operator $T$, such that $Tf(t) = f(t+h)$ for $h>0$. How do we show that $T \in L(X,X)$ (a mapping from $X$ into itself)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to show that $Tf\in X$. This is quite obvious because $t+h\in \Bbb{R}$

Than we need to show that $T(f+g)=Tf+Tg$. This is true because $\forall x\in \Bbb{R}$ one has

$$T(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(x+h)=f(x+h)+g(x+h)=Tf(x)+Tg(x)$$

Similarly we have $\forall\lambda\in\Bbb{R}$

$$T(\lambda f)(x)=(\lambda f)(x+h)=\lambda f(x+h)=\lambda Tf(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly by addition of functions the operator $T$ is linear.

Now note that $G(t)=t+h$ is a function defined on $\Bbb{R}$ and $G(\Bbb{R})=\Bbb{R}$

So $T(f):=f(G(t))=f(t+h)$ is a function defined on $\Bbb{R}$